# CSS is hiding my dropdown menu

Tags: css, web, containers, nav

I am sure it is something simple I am overlooking. But the top nav (dropdown) of my website is no longer visible. I am 100% sure it has something to do with my css applied.

```css
.ulTopmenu {margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%;  overflow:hidden;}
.liTopMenu {width: 120px; height: 40px; float: left; margin:0 4px; list-style:none; display: inline;}
.divTopMenuInnerContainer {display: inline; overflow:hidden; height:500px;width:900px;}
.divTopMenuInnerContainer{position:relative;height:100%;width:80%;}
.divTopSpliter {float:left; width:1px; height:40px; display:block; border-right:1px;}
.divTopTopSpliter {float:left; width:30px; height:1px; display:block;}

.a {
 width: 120px;
 height:25px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

/* End of General */
.divTopSubMenuSpliter {height:1px;width:auto;background:#0000; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;}


div.absolute {
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    
}
```

Comment: Share your markup please. We need a [mcve] of the current behavior. That said, you might try removing `overflow: hidden` from `.ulTopmenu` and `.divTopMenuInnerContainer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the following. Thanks for the help any way.

```css
.ulTopmenu {margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%;  overflow:visible; position:absolute;}
.liTopmenu{width: 120px; height: 40px; float: left; margin:0 4px;display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown navbar's css, it may be necessary to tell it to be visible.

Try something like this:

```
 navBar{
     visibility: visible;
 }
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did try but sadly that didn't work. I was thinking it might be the container?http://www.raffles-american-school.edu.my/usr/pagesub.aspx?pgid=51